# Why actionbar toggle has int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes which accept two string

Tags: java, android

I know action bar toogle accept two string...But why it prototype has return type integer..

ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, 
                DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
                int drawerImageRes, 
                int openDrawerContentDescRes, 
                int closeDrawerContentDescRes)

Comment: What return integer??

Comment: It is constructor. It does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The function that you shared is a constuctor, and from what I can tell in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html?#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,int,int,int)) it doesn't have any return type.

Is there another function you were referring to that accepts 2 strings as input parameters and returns an int?

Comment: no.. why it accept two string but its return type is int...Could i use string in  int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes

Comment: I'm still not sure the function you're asking about. The one you linked is of the format.

`ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity, DrawerLayout, int, int, int)`. With no return. I'm unsure where you're seeing `int function(string, string)`

Comment: I asked u why actionbar toogle constructor has ( int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes) but it accept two string just like ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle (activity:this,drawerLayout,R.string.nav_open,R.string.nav_close);

Comment: @Maroof To try and answer the more general question. Functions are allowed to have return types that differ from their input parameter types. For instance, a function can have a string as an input parameter and an int as a return, and vica versa.

`int myFunction(string myInputParameter)`
`string myFunction(int myInputParameter)`

Comment: @Maroof It doesn't need to be casted because the value returned by R.string.nav_close is an int. If you wanted to get the string value from that you would do `String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.nav_close);`

Comment: To give a little context: The R.string file stores all of its string values by reference. Meaning that if you reference R.string.some_value it will return you the int reference to that string. In order to get the string itself from this reference, we call `getResources().getString(R.string.some_value);`

Comment: If this answers your question, consider accepting it as an answer :)

Comment: Yes I understood your answer.. can u give your fb id??